# Connection string in a config external folder of the project

Tags: c#

my problem is I want to externalize the connection string in Web.config in my application and get the connection string from DBConnection.config, but I want DBConnection.config not in the same folder of the application but in C:\DBConnection. So i think it's possible to use an intermediate Temp.config file in the project folder that will read the connection string from DBConnection.config in C:\DBConnection. Thats my code at moment:

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Temp.config">
  </connectionStrings>
```

Temp.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="C:\DBConnection\DBConnection.config"></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

DBConnection.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
 <clear/>
    <add name="BarcodeEngineApiContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User Id=XX;Password=XXX;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can someone explain me how to make it works or another solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can read a connection string on application start from any file needed (e.g. read it from a text file as a string). What type of an application do you have (.net core, .Net framework)?

Comment: what is the point of **Temp.config** I couldn't see a reason. Put the path  to Web.config `<connectionStrings configSource="C:\DBConnection\DBConnection.config"></connectionStrings>` Also If you tell us what your aim is, it might be better.

Comment: I'm trying to make the connection string in a web.API application dinamic, under .NET framework. If i use <connectionStrings configSource="C:\DBConnection\DBConnection.config"></connectionStrings> directly, i get this error in The configSource attribute must be a relative physical path.

Comment: is it okay if you have your connection string in appSettings instead of connectionString?

Comment: Yes, i think would be the same for me to have the connection string in appSettings, but never did it.

Comment: You have to use a relative path not an absolute one.

Comment: Can't make it work also using \..\

Comment: @RobNone update question with those details.

Comment: Actually, my project is in C:\Users\Name\source\repos\ProjectName\Project\Project.Engine\Project.Engine.Api. I would configure the connection string inside Web.config from C:\DBConnection\DBConnection.config. How i have to configure the configSource in Web.config to make it works?

Comment: Note that you aren't limited to using the web.config file to specify where your connection strings are located. You can just use any random JSON file, an INI file, a database, or an API to get your configuration data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.File` to read the file from the path, and then you can parse it and work on it. If you need to make the path more fixable for the application (say you want to change the path), you can just add the path in your web.config, and read that path from inside the code.

Example:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionStringsPath" value="C:\DbConnection.config"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, I just created a method that returns the `ConnectionString` :

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
{
    return XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringsPath"]))
        .Descendants("connectionStrings")
        .Elements()
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => x.Attribute("connectionString").Value)
        .First();
}
```

usage :

```
var connectionString = GetConnectionString("BarcodeEngineApiContext");
```

if you want to go fancy, you can create a simple model to be deserialized.

example :

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Connection { get; set; }
}
```

then adjusting the above method to :

```
public static ConnectionString GetConnectionString(string name)
{
    return XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringsPath"]))
        .Descendants("connectionStrings")
        .Elements()
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => new ConnectionString()
        {
            Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
            Provider = x.Attribute("providerName").Value,
            Connection = x.Attribute("connectionString").Value
        }
        ).First();
}
```

Then you use it like this :

```
var barcode = GetConnectionString("BarcodeEngineApiContext");
var name = barcode.Name;
var provider = barcode.Provider;
var connectionString = barcode.Connection;
```

If you have multiple connectionStrings in the same project, you can create `Enum` with list of connections names, and pass it to the method instead of typing the name manually.

Example :

```
 public enum ConnectionStringName
{
    BarcodeEngineApiContext, 
    SecondConnectionString,
    AnotherConnectionString
}
```

and just pass it to the method :

```
var barcode = GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName.BarcodeEngineApiContext.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gettin the connection string in the variable connectionString. Actually the only problem is to give the connectionString to         public EngineApiContext() : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

Comment: @RobNone For EF, you'll have to adjust the connectionString to fit EF requirements something like this `metadata=res://*.....etc` and then you just parse it as string.

Answer (score 2):

We do something similar in my office. We have shared connection string files that live in a directory that is separate from each solution.

The TFS structure looks like this:

```
$/root
|
|- ConnectionStrings
   |- connectionStrings.DEV.config
   |- connectionStrings.QA.config
   |- connectionStrings.STG.config
   |- connectionStrings.PRD.config
|- Solution1
   |- Project1
       |- Project1.csproj
   |- Project2
       |- Project2.csproj
|- Solution2
```

Then you want to include those connectionStrings files in your .csproj like such (requires manual editing, use the relative path from your .csproj file):

```
<Content Include="..\..\ConnectionStrings\connectionStrings.DEV.config">
  <Link>connectionStrings.DEV.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Now in your web.config file you can reference them as if they were in the same directory.

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.DEV.config" />
```